# Changing multiple duplicates

Tags: rendering, materials, objects, instances

I hope you guys can help me out here.  I have searched for a very long time and I am not sure if I am wording this correctly.  So thank you for your patients.

I have an object in blender that uses duplicated group instances and it uses a lot of them.  Sometimes I need to change all of these at the same time to a new group instance.  I was hoping there were a way to select all of the instances, change them, and without editing the original version.

The object is a hair brush with multiple bristles.  I have the bristles colored for the product and then I need them rendered next to another brush with different bristles.  When I copy the whole brush with bristles, all the data comes with it.  But if I want a new color and edit the group, it changes on the original brush too.  So now when I make these changes I have to go onto the brush, select every individual bristle, go to the object panel, scroll down to the Duplication section, and select a new instance of the new group for EVERY SINGLE BRISTLE!  And I have been driven to the brink of insanity.  Please help me.  Thank you again!

Comment: Well I guess I can just make the duplicates "Real" `shift ctrl A` and then edit them quickly.  That would be fine too, not as elegant as a solution, but it would work.  Still, there should be some kind of plugin to handle changing all the duplicates at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all your dupligroup instances and on the active one change the dupli-group group. Then righ-click the input field and select *Copy to Selected*:

[image]

This will change every object in selection.

You can use this technique on many object properties.

Comment: Thank you for this!  But for some reason that option is unclickable and will not allow me to do this.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, started a new file and that works!  Thank you @Jerryno

Answer (score 2):

You can change the link of your duplicates.

In this example, all spheres are linked duplicates, we want to link some of them to the cube:

[image]

Select the objects you want to change (<kbd>Right-Click</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd> to add):

[image]

Finish selecting the source object, in this case the cube (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd>), it has to be the active object (last selected):

[image]

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to make the link and select "Object Data" in the menu:

[image]

Your objects are now linked duplicates of the cube:

[image]

Comment: @Ray This works as far as changing the directly duplicated objects `Alt D` But is does not work on the `Group Instance` items.  But thank you!  Very cool and I will use for other things.

Comment: @kevMul just make the duplicates real 1st, as you said in your comment, just 1 more step

Comment: @Ray Oh yea! Lol. That would do the trick.  Was hoping to keep them as instances though.  Thank you again!

Comment: @kevMul this will make them instanced again after link, just temporary real objects

Comment: I am not the author of the post, I just did some minor formatting changes, please direct comments to @Bithur

Comment: Sorry about that @Ray,  Thank you for your help @Bithur!  But how does it become an instance again after?  It seems to stay as an object.  Sorry for bothering you but it is extremely interesting!

Comment: @kevMul the objects are sharing the same mesh data (linked duplicates) as if you used Alt+D. Different object, sharing the same mesh. Try to edit one of them, they all change.

Comment: @Bithur I am afraid the OP does not want linked mesh data instances but group instances, they are quite different. You can read more about dupli-groups and see what they are here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliGroup Use them to also instance the object data, not only mesh data.

Comment: @Jerryno maybe you're true, but he found this "extremely interesting" so i don't understand what you mean. Do you think a problem has only 1 solution?

Comment: @Bithur Yea, Jerryno is correct in what I was looking for.  BUT having more than one solution is exactly what I need!  Thank you both for your reply's to this question.  It was driving me insane!